# LINQ Aggregate behavior of nullable types

Tags: .net, linq, nullable

Can someone explain what is going on here? Howcome *both* these things are true?

```
[TestMethod]
public void WhatIsGoingOnHere()
{
    List<int?> list = new List<int?> { 1, 2, 3, null, 5, 6 };
    Assert.AreEqual(17, list.Sum());

    int? singleSum = 1 + 2 + 3 + null + 5 + 6;

    Assert.IsNull(singleSum);
}
```

Specifically, why does the Sum() method not return 'null'? Or the singleSum not equal 17?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is the difference between using `Enumerable.Sum` and actually adding the values yourself.

The important thing here is the `null` is not zero.  At first glance you would think that `singleSum` *should* equal 17 but that would mean that we would have to assign different semantics to `null` based on the data type of the reference.  The fact that this is an `int?` makes no difference - `null` is `null` and should never be semantically equal with the numeric constant `0`.

The implementation of `Enumerable.Sum` is designed to skip over any value that is `null` in the sequence so that is why you are seeing the different behavior between the two tests.  However the second test rightly returns `null` as the compiler is smart enough to know that adding anything to `null` yields `null`.

Here is the implementation of `Enumerable.Sum` that accepts a parameter of `int?`:

```
public static int? Sum(this IEnumerable<int?> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    int num = 0;
    foreach (int? nullable in source)
    {
        // As you can see here it is explicitly designed to
        // skip over any null values
        if (nullable.HasValue)
        {
            num += nullable.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
    return new int?(num);
}
```

Comment: I totally get why singelSum is null, not 17 - because null is just null... fully with you there :) I guess my question was more, howcome Sum() didn't return null, too...

Answer (score 6):

The `.Sum()` method of nullable types ignores all `null` values:

**MSDN:** [`Enumerable.Sum Method (IEnumerable<Nullable<Int32>>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065.aspx)

> > **Remarks**
> >
> > The result does not include values that are null.

Whereas if you add any number via `+` to `null` the result is `null`.

As Andrew Hare noted, it doesn't make sense to add a number to `null`: `null` is not `0`; it is just not a number.

Comment: thanks for the link... looks like it's just how it works. I get that now - cheers :)

Comment: genuinely sorry I couldn't mark both these answer as correct... +1 from me, anyhow! thanks